# Insert data from 1 table to another table in my local sql

Tags: sql-server

Hi I need to run this script to insert data from another server to my local sql server. How I can identify the path?
CMMS is the name of the table that is in my local sql. My pc name is itfg234. what should I replace for CMMS in this query.

```
 SELECT * INTO CMMS
 FROM (
 SELECT N'178670' AS [_IdxIdentity], N'E94E6A98-B71A-41ED-8B4B-F6472BA72ECD' AS    [Contract_Other_DateBooked] ) t;
```

GO

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
customer_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
customer_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE employee(
emp_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
emp_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
contact_no VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
```

I need insert data from customer to employees

```
INSERT customer SELECT customer_id, customer_name, address FROM employee;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the destination table already exists then you can't use `SELECT * INTO` or you'll get error

> There is already an object named 'CMMS' in the database.

`SELECT INTO` creates the destination table. Use `INSERT INTO dbo.CMMS ([column names])` instead.

The query is cut off so I can't see the entire subquery but I'll just mention you should give it an alias or you may get

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

If you are planning to run the command on the source server I recommend that you design it to run on the destination server and select from source using a linked server or `OPENROWSET` function. It's easier to pull data than push it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you @DBNull, I edited my question with the whole query, this is only for 1 row of data. Imagin for thousond record how I can convert the Select into to insert into? I have to change all the format then and it is so time cosuming. Do you know any simlper way?

Comment: Nikta, I did not realize the full query had personal data in it. You should edit it to remove the personal data.

Comment: As for the question, both SELECT INTO and INSERT INTO allow you to insert the results of a query into a table. Like so, 

`INSERT INTO dbo.CMMS (columnA, columnB, columnC...) 
SELECT column1, column2, column3...
FROM linked server name.database name.dbo.source table name WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE blah blah blah `

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name LIKE old_table_name; 
INSERT new_table_name SELECT * FROM old_table_name;
```

hope this one help you.